# Application failed codesign verification. What do I do?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4, certificate

Xcode gives me this warning when I build the app for release.

> Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Do I need to delete all entries from my keychain and redo getting a certificate, provisioning profile, etc?

I can build and debug on the iPhone and iPad without a problem.

If you know how I can solve this dilemma, please provide exact steps or a way for me to contact you about this.

Thanks

----UPDATE -----

> Build Log
>
> Validate build/Release-iphoneos/iApp.app
>   cd "/Users/iosdeveloper/Documents/Programming/iPad/iApp HD"
>   setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation "/Users/iosdeveloper/Documents/Programming/iPad/iApp HD/build/Release-iphoneos/iApp.app"
>
> warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
>   Executable=/Users/iosdeveloper/Documents/Programming/iPad/iApp HD/build/Release-iphoneos/iApp.app/iApp
>   codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
>   /Users/iosdeveloper/Documents/Programming/iPad/iApp HD/build/Release-iphoneos/iApp.app: valid on disk
>   /Users/iosdeveloper/Documents/Programming/iPad/iApp HD/build/Release-iphoneos/iApp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
>   test-requirement: failed to satisfy code requirement(s)
>   codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: failed to execute codesign(1)
>    - (null)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably need to check what code signing profile is selected in your distribution build properties.

Comment: I checked it and set it to Automatic.

Comment: Under code signing identity, you need to select your code signing profile specifically.

Comment: Check this post for other ideas, might be to do with the validation feature: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/xcode-32-build-and-archive.html

Comment: That article talks about AdHoc. I'm trying to get my App in the AppStore

Comment: Yeah the validation will run with both though.  Does your app identifier match what the profile is signed for? that could also be the problem. You also might want to look inside your project pbxproj file to see if there is an error in there and its not using the profile it should be for the distribution build.

Comment: I deleted all certificates and profiles from my computer. I also deleted the Apple WWDR certificate. I think I'm going to have to start over.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the checklist I go through when I've hit this:

1. Clean all targets, exit Xcode, then go drag the build folder from your project to the trash.
2. Do the Get Info on your project, make sure the Code Signing Entitlements and Code Signing Identity are selected correctly.  Do the same for your Targets.
3. Login to the iOS Provisioning Portal and make sure the Distribution certificate has not expired.  Also check the Distribution Provisioning Profile and make sure it is Active.  Make sure the Certificate is properly in your Keychain and the Distribution profile is in Xcode Organizer (if you have multiple of the same one, delete all but the correct one and redo step #2).
4. Look at your Build Results on the failure and identify which profile it is actually using and make sure it is the right one.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! In my case Entitlements.plist was selected, but invalid. I created a new one in the New File... wizard and used that instead and got rid of the above error. So a wrong entitlements.plist will produce the code sign validation error above.

Comment: Where is the build folder located?

Comment: With the latest Xcode, it is probably /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/DerivedData - I would close Xcode and drag the Build folder for your project under DerivedData to the trash.  You can just delete the whole project, but that will get rid of indexes and logs - maybe not a big deal.

Comment: +1 Checking the code signing settings for targets is what did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your target is "Development" but Xcode applied some of distribution settings to it, so the warning simply means your ad-hoc build has no valid AppStore submission certificate. Go to your target settings, choose the Release configuration and uncheck "Validate Built Product" option.

Comment: Hello, it's very late for an answer, but i've had a similar problem : for an unknown reason, my target "development" wanted to validate the product (as if it was a "distribution" target). Your solution works perfectly and was very clear ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[Create your iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile for App Store Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action)

Answer (score 0):

Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
i am got the Same Warning Message...

I just Changed to iOs Deployment target 4.3 to 3.2.2 its works perfectly .....

Answer (score 0):

Note: you may have to go to XCode's "Project" and select "Edit Active Target (appname)",
which is near the bottom of the list ... in the new pane that opens, select "Build", then
under "Code Signing Identity" select your distribution provision.  Note that this seems
to be editing a different thing than "Project" / "Edit Project" (editing "target" instead
of "project").  I found I had to edit both project and target's code signing identities.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. It was due to installing Xcode 4.0.2 and 4.2 preview 3 at the same time. Removed both (through the provided uninstall scripts):

```
<Xcodedir>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Then rebooted and installed 4.0.2 and it works :/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the codesign process a headache - I always shudder when I get am ready to use Ad Hoc distribution to beta test.  After the usual round of errors and failed fix attempts I ignored the "application failed codesign" error and sent the build to a beta tester.  It worked without issue.

Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

In the build log provided in the -UPDATE- section of the original post the *root cause* of the failed signature verification is expressed with the text: 
**"test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)"**. That particular flavor of failed signature verification is almost always caused by mistakenly signing your app with an iPhone Developer profile instead of an iPhone Distribution profile.

It can be confirmed with the steps in "[How do I verify the certificate that was used to sign my app?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG8)". If the certificate "Identity" is "iPhone Developer: YOUR_NAME" instead of "iPhone Distribution: ..." that is the reason for the **"Application failed codesign verification"** error, and you can resolve it by performing the following steps:

1a). if you have not yet created an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile yet, that is done on the "Distribution" tab of the ["Provisioning" Section of the iOS Portal site](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action).

***Note**, the "Distribution" tab is only available to Team Members whose role is either "Agent" (the one who signed up for the iOS Developer Program), or "Admin" (those that the Agent grant access to app-distribution capabilities).*

1b). if you're fairly certain you have an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile installed in your Xcode profile library, you can verify it is an App Store profile as well as the App ID associated to it by using the steps in section  [How do I confirm my Provisioning Profile is for App Store distribution?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG35)

2). verify that your Scheme 'Archive' task is mapped to "Release" using the steps in section: 
"[Creating an Application Archive](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG12)"

3). check that you have an your App Store provisioning profile assigned to your "Release" Code Signing Identity using the steps in section 
"[Assigning Provisioning Profiles to Build Configurations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG7)".

***Note**: it's important to make these changes at the Target level Build Settings, versus the Project level ones, as Target settings override Project ones...you can think of the Project level build settings as 'defaults' to populate target settings (and any future targets) with. Also, Ensure the "All" button is depressed in the upper-left corner of  Target Build Settings to reveal the "Code Signing Identity" section.*

4). retry your Product > Archive.

If the issue persists after the above, I recommend continuing onto Apple's complete list of potential causes of this error at the following URL ["How do I resolve the error: Application failed codesign verification?"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved when I noticed that I only had a "team" provisioning profile, and the details in iOS Dev Center told me that it was not a profile fit for development because it had no device attached. So I created a second provisioning profile, which let me check the box for my device so that it had a device attached.

Then when validating or submitting the app from the Organizer window (after pressing 'Build and archive'), I first made the mistake of selecting this new profile as the code signing profile. That was wrong. The profile that worked was iPhone Developer.

Good luck!

PS: This whole submission process is a heap of abacadabra. Do you really have to create a zillion distribution profiles, provisioning profiles, etc.? It hasn't encouraged me in any way to better test my app. I already did that before I chose to upload, and clicking a hundred buttons labeled 'Create','Download' and 'Submit' isn't really a quality control process that added anything (well except being forced to buy an iPad and test on that). Who ever said iOS was developer friendly?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the Archive scheme did not have Build Configuration of App Store, but of Release.  To change this, go to Product -> Edit scheme, select Archive on left side and change Build Configuration to App Store.  I am assuming the code signing is configured properly (with distribution certificate).

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a new certificate without refreshing the provisioning profiles

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting the Archive that's not validating from the Organizer, closed and reopened Xcode and built for Archiving again.

I then chose Archive from the drop down menu.  After doing that my app passed validation.

Hope that helps.