# iOS codesign error

Tags: iphone, codesign

I continuously get the following warning when I build my iPhone application:

Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

But my application still runs. Why is this occurring? Can someone help? I updated my application and the App Store approved it, but now it crashes everytime anyone runs it (after installing the update) and I have no idea why. And now, I can't even get this warning to go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my [todo list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892148/application-failed-codesign-verification-what-do-i-do/3892369#3892369) when I've run across this.

1) Clean all targets, exit Xcode, then go drag the build folder from your project to the trash.

2) Do the Get Info on your project, make sure the Code Signing Entitlements and Code Signing Identity are selected correctly.  Do the same for your Targets.

3) Login to the iOS Provisioning Portal and make sure the Distribution certificate has not expired.  Also check the Distribution Provisioning Profile and make sure it is Active.  Make sure the Certificate is properly in your Keychain and the Distribution profile is in Xcode Organizer (if you have multiple of the same one, delete all but the correct one and redo step #2).

4) Look at your Build Results on the failure and identify which profile it is actually using and make sure it is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a bug in Xcode, I have read somewhere people reporting that warning after upgrading it. I have the same problem, I can compile and run the App, I have already released the App to the AppStore, but I just can't get rid of that annoying warning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a try to reset Keychain, before I encounter a problem that show my certificate was expired or invalid and I can not run with mobile, then I reset Keychain, then it worked well.