# Application failed codesign verification (Updating app)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, distribution, code-signing

I've been struggling with this for the past week and can't find a single solution that works. I'm updating my app and when I validate it I get the error:

`application failed codesign verification. the signature was invalid, or it was not sign with an Apple submission certificate`

When I first made the app I was running Xcode 3.x, currently it's 4.1. I'm using the same distribution profile, same app ID, edited the archive scheme to use distribution.

Someone please please please help. This is killing me

Comment: Check whether your certificate is till now valid. I think xcode version is not a problem for this.

Comment: I did, the certificate is still valid

Comment: Make sure you have the correct Code Signing certificate selected

Comment: Just checked again, I do

Comment: No not yet, I've been trying the solutions on the links you gave me, but haven't found one that works yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with these links.Hope you will get in this.

1. [Application failed codesign verification. What do I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892148/application-failed-codesign-verification-what-do-i-do)
2. [How to fix "failed codesign verification" of an iPhone project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879473/how-to-fix-failed-codesign-verification-of-an-iphone-project)