# Application failed codesign verification due to invalid entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, icloud, code-signing-entitlements

I've googled the crap out of this and can't find any solutions. It happened to me a few months ago as well when I was updating a different app.

I'm running Xcode 4.2.

Build log:

```
Validate /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThoughtSpreader-gpmecrthgzqfboguxycmyxiaijjc/ArchiveIntermediates/ParseStarterProject/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/ThoughtSpreader.app
cd "/Users/chrismanahan/Downloads/ParseStarterProject 2"
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThoughtSpreader-gpmecrthgzqfboguxycmyxiaijjc/ArchiveIntermediates/ParseStarterProject/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/ThoughtSpreader.app

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThoughtSpreader-gpmecrthgzqfboguxycmyxiaijjc/ArchiveIntermediates/ParseStarterProject/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/ThoughtSpreader.app/ThoughtSpreader
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier, 894BCL9P67.com.manahan.thoughtspreader
Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers, <CFArray 0x10d10aa10 [0x7fff7d96cea0]>{type = mutable-small, count = 1, values = (
0 : <CFString 0x10d10a860 [0x7fff7d96cea0]>{contents = "894BCL9P67.com.manahan.thoughtspreader"}
)}
AssertMacros: filter_entitlements(entitlements_whitelist, entitlements_requested, allowable_entitlements),  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 932
- (null)
```

Comment: I think I had a similar problem, I fixed it by not clicking 'Always Allow' when the keychain certificate prompts and just click 'Allow'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I bet the key (pardon the pun?) to your problem is here:

```
Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier, 894BCL9P67.com.manahan.thoughtspreader
Illegal entitlement key/value pair: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers, <CFArray 0x10d10aa10 [0x7fff7d96cea0]>{type = mutable-small, count = 1, values = (...
```

Is your app id still `894BCL9P67.com.manahan.thoughtspreader`?

Or have these keys changed / need to be updated? (per the instructions [here](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2011_06_01_archive.html)?)

That link suggests you need the team id and not your app id bundle seed. YMMV. (Apple documents those keys [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/EntitlementKeyReference.pdf), suggests the same thing. I'm guessing you're using iCloud, or set your project up to use it initially.)

For anyone not familiar w/ iCloud setup, you can change the value of those keys here:

[image: iCloud entitlements]

That settings pane is part of  the target summary, under your project file. Select the target you want and the Summary 'tab', like so (then scroll to the bottom):

[image: Summary page]

Apple's docs for configuring these are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1).

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced such kind of problems and the best way to solve this problem is again create an App ID and a Provisioning profile -> delete the build folder of your app -> clean your project-> downlaod the profile-> double click on the profile, so it will automatically open it into the keychain-> Refresh it -> now drag and drop the new provisioning profile into your project -> Now in your project go to the info of your project in build tab go to code signing identity and choose the new one.

Now go to itunes and upload it through **Application Loader**

```
Hope it helps as it did mine. :)
```

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately not the solution for me :/ Thank you though

Comment: Sad, hey ur log says "The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate." tell me whether u r trying to deploy on iphone or publish on Apple? Hope u know the difference between Developer and Distributor certificate(dont mind plz if u know)

Comment: PLz check this link also, it has same problem.... see all solutions            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892148/application-failed-codesign-verification-what-do-i-do

Comment: I'm publishing to Apple, and yes, I do know the difference, I've been doing this for a year and never had a problem until I upgraded Xcode then it just sh*ts on me every chance it gets. I do have it signed with the distribution profile. Thanks for the link, I'll be looking through all the solutions today

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too, and what fixed for me:

In the iPhone Dev Center, when setting up the App ID, I'd forgotten to check the box for "Enable for iCloud".  Going back and turning that on, then regenerating the provisioning profiles fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

After an unwilling upgrade to Xcode 5 and iOS 7 on my iPad, and spending several agonizing hours of trying to narrow down where the offending ID was coming from, I had to manually remove every mention of these provisioning profiles by editing the *.pbxproj file, in *.xcodeproj directory. This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I encounter this error, it is because either Xcode randomly deleted my certificates (backups, backups, backups), or I forgot to switch from the distribution certificate back to the development certificate.  Go into Build Settings and verify that you have the correct (or even existent) certificates, then clean, clean build folder, and run.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, XCode messes with the iPhone identities it uses to sign your application.( and sometimes, i works again after 3 cleans,

1. Clean your keychain from expired certificates
2. check your projects build settings, you might have several 'iPhone distribution' profiles, and maybe XCode is selecting the wrong one. (i've found out that XCode often kept references of old provisioning profiles that were deleted : i  had to manually remove mentions of these provisioning profiles, editing the *.pbxproj file, in *.xcodeproj directory)
3. Since last versions of XCode, provisioning profiles can be retrieved automatically by XCode organizer... it works (sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent many days trying to solve it, i think the easier solution is to create a new project and import all your code and xib there!
it solved my problem!