# no matter what keep getting "Application failed to code sign" error when trying to archive my app for submission to the app store

Tags: iphone, certificate, code-signing

i have tried EVERYTHING, looked through dozens of articles and repeatedly made sure my certs were valid and profiles were legitimate, but i keep getting this error

**warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was                   not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/roozmahdavian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chances-clvdkoglyqraiefynxcmcsaqgjwg/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Chances.app/Chances
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
/Users/roozmahdavian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chances-clvdkoglyqraiefynxcmcsaqgjwg/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Chances.app: valid on disk
/Users/roozmahdavian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chances-clvdkoglyqraiefynxcmcsaqgjwg/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Chances.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: failed to execute codesign(1)**

what am i supposed to do to fix this? its getting very frustrating

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-x-xxxxx-doesnt-match-any-iden

Comment: check this:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-x-xxxxx-doesnt-match-any-iden

Answer (score 0):

the App Store provisioning file for this app is corrupt or  not available on your mac, or on Apples servers... delete the App Store provisioning file from the iOS dev dashboard, then recreate it, download it, and it works

Before you delete it, make sure other parts are ok and problem is only this one ...

Comment: also check this links maybe it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892148/application-failed-codesign-verification-what-do-i-do